# Loading scripts async in next.js

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, deferred

I have a very small page in next.js that simply says `Finding you a game...`
I need it to render almost instantaneously.

The problem is, it needs to load some heavy libraries to find the game in the first place.
Currently, next.js is loading those libraries before showing `Finding you a game...`.

What I want to do is to mark all the dependencies as `async` or `defer` so that the page renders first and then the dependencies get loaded.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. I have a similar problem

Comment: Sort of. I created some extra pages: landing, finding, and game. `Landing` page has no dependencies, and the action button simply links to the `finding` page. The finding page then uses dynamic components from next.js to display the "finding game" message asap while loading the dependencies. When the game is found the user is redirected to the `game` page. Let me know if you need a more thorough explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your usecase is a bit different. I am trying to load a script that is not imported, if that makes sense. It's a paypal script in the head of the page  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778707/wait-for-loading-paypal-script-in-nextjs-page  .Thank you though