# wait for loading paypal script in nextjs page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have this code that is supposed to render the PayPal buttons.

```
    <Head>
      <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=KEY"></script>
    </Head>
```

I load the PayPal buttons in the componentDidMount method

```
componentDidMount() {
    paypal
.Buttons({
  createOrder: (data, actions)=> {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: amount,
          },
        }],
    });
  },
  onCancel: function(data){
    //console.log(data)

  },
  onError: function(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
})
.render("#paypal");
 }




<div id="paypal" className=""></div>
```

on the first page load, the page throws an error that PayPal is not defined I am guessing because the script is not loaded fully when the componentDidMount method is called.
How can I wait until the script is loaded for the buttons to be rendered properly?

Comment: You can try to use this approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041377/706798. I can elaborate if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const addPayPalScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID}`;
    // script.setAttribute("data-namespace", "paypal_sdk");

    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => {
      setSdkReady(true);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  };
```

script.onload will flag that it is ready. Track it in useState

```
   const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);
```

then call addPayPalScript inside useEffect or componentDidMount. I use useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(orderDetailRequestStart(paramsId));

  if (!window.paypal) {
    addPayPalScript();
  } else {
    // flags that it is ready
    setSdkReady(true);
  }

}, []);
```